# modify properties file in META-INF

Tags: java, maven-2, properties, jar

I'm using maven and storing a properties file in `src/main/resources` which I can read fine like:

```
properties.loadFromXML(this.getClass().getClassLoader().
                        getResourceAsStream("META-INF/properties.xml");
```

Is it possible to then write to this file when it is packaged up as a jar? I've tried the following:

```
properties.storeToXML(new FileOutputStream(new File(this.getClass().getClassLoader().
                        getResource("META-INF/properties.xml").toURI())), "");
```

This works in Eclipse because it is saving the file to `target/classes/META-INF`, but not when packaged as a jar, so is it possible to achieve the same thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to then write to this file when it is packaged up as a jar?

Short answer: no, it is not possible, a jar file is a file, not a directory. And actually, you generally don't write properties files back to a jar file.

You should put that properties file on the classpath on the local file system, outside a JAR.

Answer (score 0):

It's always possible to modify a packaged file by unpacking, rewriting and re-packing. Sometimes this is the easiest approach.

A Jar file is essentially a renamed `.ZIP` file. Java has classes for accessing files within a .Zip file, and you could (if sufficiently motivated) write yourself a program to do this.

Alternatively, I'm pretty sure there are `ant` tasks that can do this too (think creative use of the `jar` task), and there are POM plugins available to run ant tasks from Maven.